# How to group multiple workflows in github actions?

Tags: github-actions

[Like "Build" in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KiNP.png)

I want run workflows parallel, when all done then start next workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matrix:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs

It will create parallel jobs with desired parameters.

And then it will run the next `steps` in your workflow.

If you really want to trigger a different workflow, you can use:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/trigger-external-workflow
but I have a feeling you are rather missing proper naming in your question.
Your screenshot is showing a single workflow, with multiple jobs, and Build jobs using a matrix that allows parallel execution of steps.